# No such file or directory when running cd in bash function with path that is indeed correct

Tags: bash

So I'm not very educated on Bash but I've been stumped on this. The `switchto` function is to provide me an easy way to jump between projects on the command line.

```
source ~/.profile
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"

switchto () (
        cd "~/Projects/$1.com/wp-content/themes/$1"
)
```

Everything SEEMS right to me, but it keeps saying if I run for example `switchto example`:

```
-bash: cd: ~/Projects/example.com/wp-content/themes/example: No such file or directory
```

I've verified again and again the the directory does indeed exist. I'm new to bash so I'm not sure if it's something simple I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tilde `~` is not expanded to your home directory if it is quoted.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html

> `Tilde Expansion`
>
> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~`), all of the characters up to the first unquoted slash (or all characters, 
>       if there is no unquoted slash) are considered a *tilde-prefix*. If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, 
>       the characters in the tilde-prefix following the tilde are treated as a possible *login name*. If this login name is the 
>       null string, the tilde is replaced with the value of the `HOME` shell variable. If `HOME` is unset, the home directory of 
>       the user executing the shell is substituted instead. Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is replaced with the home directory associated
>       with the specified login name.

So you can use (with curly braces):

```
switchto () {
    cd ~/"Projects/$1.com/wp-content/themes/$1"
}
```

and you can combine your two `PATH` definitions with

```
  export PATH=~/bin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```