# Iterating through a command list using heredoc

Tags: here-document, eval

This works fine:

```
$ eval 'echo "1" > ~/Desktop/in/foo'
```

But not this:

```
$ while IFS= read _cmd; do eval "$_cmd"; done < <(cat << EOF
'echo "1" > ~/Desktop/in/foo'
'echo "2" > ~/Desktop/in/bar'
EOF
)
bash: echo "1" > ~/Desktop/in/foo: No such file or directory
bash: echo "2" > ~/Desktop/in/bar: No such file or directory
```

How to fix it?

---

update

As suggested, dropping single quotes works, but not for this variation (ditto by surrounding only the filename with single quotes):

```
$ while IFS= read _cmd; do eval "$_cmd"; done < <(cat << EOF 
echo "1" > ~/Desktop/in/foo (bis)
echo "2" > ~/Desktop/in/bar
EOF
)
```

---

Altogether with the provided solution:

```
"$SHELL" << EOF
echo "1" > ~/Desktop/in/'foo (bis)'
echo "2" > ~/Desktop/in/bar
EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `eval 'echo "1" > ~/Desktop/in/foo'`, the shell removes the single-quotes, then `eval` evaluates `echo "1" > ~/Desktop/in/foo`.

When you run `eval "$_cmd"` (in your pre-update code), the shell expands `$_cmd` and removes the double quotes, then `eval` evaluates `'echo "1" > ~/Desktop/in/foo'`. Note the single quotes. You don't want `eval` to see them, remove them from the here document.

In your updated code you probably want `eval` to evaluate `echo "1" > ~/Desktop/in/'foo (bis)'`, so use this exact line in the here document.

---

Well, "exact" is not the right word in general. In general `<< EOF` (as opposed to e.g. `<< 'EOF'`) expands variables and few other things in the here document (there are none in your example, but in general this is how it works). Then `IFS= read _cmd` is not [`IFS= read -r _cmd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/108618). Finally `eval` gets a string which is not necessarily the *exact* string you used.

Evaluating line by line makes evaluating multi-line commands impossible.

Unless you really want to rely on what `<< EOF` and `IFS= read` do to the string(s) you provide (and you know what you're doing), just write the code directly in the script. After all, you want the shell interpreting the script to evaluate `echo "1" > ~/Desktop/in/foo`. It's not even you want some other shell process. There is no need for a here document here.

I guess preprocessing code for another shell process may make sense (in some cases and when you're careful), but then you should use e.g. `bash << EOF`, not `read`.

---

Another thing: the snippet `done < <(cat << EOF` can be simplified to `done << EOF` (note this change requires removing the `)` from the end of your code).

Comment: "you probably want eval to evaluate echo "1" > '~/Desktop/in/foo (bis)', so use this exact line in the here document." But it's faulty.

Comment: @Erwann I forgot [the tilde must not be quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545426/108618). Fixed now, I hope.

Comment: I guess you mean `bash < <(cat << EOF...` instead of `bash << EOF`, right? (the latter yields `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'`)

Comment: @Erwann No, I mean `bash << EOF`. There is no `(` in it. I think your contraption with `cat` works because it provides `(` matching the `)` you had. My guess is you did not remove this `)` when using `bash << EOF`, hence the error. The real fix is in removing the `)`, not in [voodoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_programming) with `cat`.

Comment: "There is no need for a here document here." It's to be able to run the code from the command line, as one block.

Comment: @Erwann Still there is no need for a here document here. :) Type `{`, Enter, then (possibly multi-line) code, place sole `}` in the last line; hit Enter. Or (in Bash) Ctrl+x, Ctrl+e, type the code, save and exit the editor (interesting variant [here](https://superuser.com/q/1601543/432690), other shells may provide similar functionality). Next time do not fall into [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310).